# Telegram REST API parse_mode=html

Tags: curl, telegram, telegram-bot

I have the following CURL request

```
 curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxx/sendMessage -d chat_id=-xxxx -d text="Remember guys,%0A%0A\<b\>THERE IS NO GLOBAL ROM, NO PLAYSTORE, NO GOOGLE PAY, NO ROOT, NO BOOTLOADER UNLOCK\!\</b\>,%0A%0AI will let you know when that changes, for more information on your watch, and how to remove chinese apps please visit http://miwatch.cf" -d "parse_mode='html'"
```

Im trying to send in html so i can have newline and bold text, but I am getting

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode"
```

I've also tried HTML/Markdown/MARKDOWN/markdown, same response every time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HTML` parse_mode should not be quoted:

`-d "parse_mode='html'"` ----> `-d parse_mode=HTML`.

I've used single-quotes around the `text` so that my terminal [won't try to expand the 'special chars'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash);

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<mytoken>/sendMessage -d chat_id=1234567 -d text='Remember guys, <b>THERE IS NO GLOBAL ROM, NO PLAYSTORE, NO GOOGLE PAY, NO ROOT, NO BOOTLOADER UNLOCK!</b>, will let you know when that changes, for more information on your watch, and how to remove chinese apps please visit http://miwatch.cf' -d parse_mode=HTML
```

[image]